# How nested 'for' loops are inserting newlines in this program automatically?

Tags: for-loop, nested, alphanumeric

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int alpha,numeric;

for(alpha='A';alpha<'K';alpha++)
  {
    for(numeric=0;numeric<10;numeric++)
       {

        printf("%c%d\t",alpha,numeric);

       }
  }
return 0;
}
```

The output I got is as follows.

A0      A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A6      A7      A8      A9

B0      B1      B2      B3      B4      B5      B6      B7      B8      B9

C0      C1      C2      C3      C4      C5      C6      C7      C8      C9

D0      D1      D2      D3      D4      D5      D6      D7      D8      D9

E0      E1      E2      E3      E4      E5      E6      E7      E8      E9

F0      F1      F2      F3      F4      F5      F6      F7      F8      F9

G0      G1      G2      G3      G4      G5      G6      G7      G8      G9

H0      H1      H2      H3      H4      H5      H6      H7      H8      H9

I0      I1      I2      I3      I4      I5      I6      I7      I8      I9

J0      J1      J2      J3      J4      J5      J6      J7      J8      J9

But, more neat and in form of a matrix, without any space between lines.
Someone please tell me how the printing is entering to new line even though there is no newline(\n) character in the program.

Comment: I guess it is not inserting a new line , rather the output is wrapping to next line

Comment: try to use '  '(double space) instead of '\t'

Comment: Oh, yeah! You are right. It's wrapping the text. Thanks!!